# Asp.Net Extracting data from deep within a dictionary<string,object>-

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, dictionary

Relatively newbie here with a little question. I been extracting a json string that looks like this (in this case it is a modified return from Facebook oauth2.

> {"id":"555555555555555","name":"Monkey
>   Man","last_name":"Man","first_name":"Monkey","email":"test\u0040someaccount.com","location":{"id":"555555555555555","name":"Jungle,
>   North
>   Carolina"},"gender":"male","work":[{"employer":{"id":"555555555555555","name":"Big
>   Boss makes me work"}:"projects":{"current":"doing stuff",
>   "previous":"other
>   stuff"},"location":{"id":"555555555555555","name":"Jungle, North
>   Carolina"},"position":{"id":"555555555555555","name":"IT
>   monkey"},"start_date":"2010-09"}],"picture":"http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/static-ak/rsrc.php/v1/yo/r/5555555-555.gif"}

Well I am able to extract everything to a the dictionary by using the following code

```
 JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    Dictionary<string, object> dict = ser.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,object>>(json);
```

I then extract the data as following from the dictionary and store them in an object called contact which is pretty much just a collection of strings.

```
    if (d.ContainsKey("email"))
    {
        c.email = d["email"].ToString();
    }
    else
        c.email = "";
```

I did it this way as I was not gaurenteed the information fields will all be there.

If there is an object set in the value such as with the address I use a modified code (thanks to the guy who showed me how to do that) like following.

```
c.location = (d["location"] as Dictionary<string, object>)["name"].ToString();
```

Now come the difficult part that I am stuck on.

I am trying to extract the employer name "Big Boss makes me work" from the following part of the string...

> "work":[{"employer":{"id":"555555555555555","name":"Big Boss makes me
>   work"}:"projects":{"current":"doing stuff", "previous":"other
>   stuff"},"location":{"id":"555555555555555","name":"Jungle, North
>   Carolina"},"position":{"id":"555555555555555","name":"IT
>   monkey"},"start_date":"2010-09"}]

It is storing the data down within an array inside of other objects and I have no idea how to get to the information to extract it, or even how to extract information like this from live oauth2...

> "addresses": { "personal": { "street": null, "street_2": null, "city":
>   "Jungle", "state": "NC", "postal_code": "28677", "region": "United
>   States" }, "business": { "street": "Tree Street", "street_2": null,
>   "city": "Jungle", "state": "NC", "postal_code": "28677", "region":
>   "United States" } }

As you can see this goes three levels deep so my (d["location"] as Dictionary)["name"].ToString(); is pretty useless here. How would you go about getting say the street name from this?

I hope my questions aren't too vague or random. I just need some advice on properly extracting data from the dictionary objects. The ways I come up with involve editing the json string and that causes alsorts of problems as I just don't understand the dictionary object well enough to figure this out on my own

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Running your JSON through jsonlint.com (and correcting it slightly), it looks like this formatted:

```
{
    "id": "555555555555555",
    "name": "Monkey Man",
    "last_name": "Man",
    "first_name": "Monkey",
    "email": "test@someaccount.com",
    "location": {
        "id": "555555555555555",
        "name": "Jungle, North Carolina"
    },
    "gender": "male",
    "work": [
        {
            "employer": {
                "id": "555555555555555",
                "name": "Big Boss makes me work"
            },
            "projects": {
                "current": "doing stuff",
                "previous": "other stuff"
            },
            "location": {
                "id": "555555555555555",
                "name": "Jungle, North Carolina"
            },
            "position": {
                "id": "555555555555555",
                "name": "IT monkey"
            },
            "start_date": "2010-09"
        }
    ],
    "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/static-ak/rsrc.php/v1/yo/r/5555555-555.gif"
}
```

Your JSON data in this case just isn't really suitable to be serialized to a straightforward Dictionary object, so that's not really the way to go here.

The easier way to do is to create a C# class that has defined properties the same as the Javascript object you're de-serializaing. Then, deserialize the JSON as that object and you should be able to access the ""Big Boss makes me work" value should be at `objectFromJson.work[0].employer.name`  .